# How can I override an existing classes method, specifically a file's close method?

Tags: python

I am asking this question, due to this issue => https://github.com/minio/minio-py/issues/1276 where MinIO SDK closes the file I passed from HTTPx client somewhere that I cant exactly pinpoint, and HTTPx tries to seek a closed file when we get the response, causing a scene where everything works but file cant be seeked because it is closed. So I need a bandaid fix.

Tried doing =>

```py
    class BandAidTempFileFix(StarletteUploadFile):
        def __init__(self, file):
            super().__init__(file)
            self._file = file

        def __enter__(self):
            return self

        def __exit__(self, *args):
            pass

        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            return getattr(self._file, attr)

        def close(self):
            pass
    BandAidTempFileFix(document.file)
```

Where document.file is [Starlette's Upload File](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#:%7E:text=UploadFile%20has%20the%20following%20attributes%3A), which is basically a SpooledTemporaryFile wrapper from tempfile standard library, but I get illegal seek again when I use the file, meaning MinIO SDK closed the file again somewhere down the road.

...help?

Comment: Read issue if you want to know more about how I found myself in this hole.